# Load script tag as a string and append it to html header

Tags: javascript, html, script-tag

I want to load some script tag from the server as a string and to append it to HTML header, but even though I can append it, it doesn't execute. Here is the simplified HTML file to illustrate this situation:

```
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <script>
        function htmlStringToElement(htmlString) {
            var template = document.createElement('template');
            htmlString = htmlString.trim();
            template.innerHTML = htmlString;
            return template.content.firstChild;
        }

        //Mocking http request
        setTimeout(function() {
            var httpResponseMock = '<script>alert("HELLO FROM HTTP RESPONSE!");<\/script>'; 
            var script = htmlStringToElement(httpResponseMock);
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
```

I suppose that the reason is that header has already been rendered when the script is added dynamically but is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Jquery,

```
var httpResponseMock = '<script><\/script>'; 
$('head').append(httpResponseMock);
```

and with javascript

```
var httpResponseMock = '<script><\/script>'; 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(httpResponseMock);
```

Comment: Well it works if it's done with jQuery as you did in a first example, but the second example without jQuery doesn't work. Anyway jQuery approach is very usefull! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

don't ever use innerHTML unless you know what you are doing.
if you really want to dynamically inject script into the document just do this or use eval:

```js
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "console.log('yay it works!');";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

the `appendChild` is running it.

Comment: Thanks! This works well. I just added one additional step between because I receive whole script tag as a pure string, but your solution was the key thing to make this work.

   var httpResponseMock = '<script>alert("HELLO FROM HTTP RESPONSE!");<\/script>'; 

   var parsedScriptFromHttpResponse = htmlStringToElement(httpResponseMock);

   
   const script = document.createElement("script");

   script.textContent = parsedScriptFromHttpResponse.text;

   document.head.appendChild(script);

Answer (score 0):

There is a longer discussion in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) about dynamic loading of JS. The simple answer in this case is to use `eval` to evaluate the script content. Please note though that using `eval` is considered mostly a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil).